# Xamarin Android Emulator Will Not Finish Booting Up in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, emulation

I am having trouble with launching my Android Emulator in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

What happens is that I launch the emulator (MyEmu), it just stays screen showing the "Android" logo. It doesn't freeze or anything, it just doesn't finish loading. I've tried multiple times, with waiting an hour for a few of those tries.

The program I am running is compiles with Android Version: API Level 21, as shown in my first attachment.

[image]

I tried the two default emulators given when on the "Android Emulator Manager" screen to see if any emulator would work and they both booted up within 20 or so seconds.

[image]

Here is a snapshot of my "Android SDK Manager". Everything seemingly required is installed, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

[image]

Finally, here is a snapshot of the "MyEmu" emulator I am trying to create.

[image]

I'm not sure what the problem could be.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The Android emulator is a Google tool and has nothing to do with Xamarin.  Xamarin does have their own (arguably much better) emulator - https://xamarin.com/android-player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your android emulator is Visual Studio?

Is it the Xamarin one (XAP) or the Microsoft one?

Both rely, afaik, on Hyper-V. So most likely, your issues are related to that. Either Hyper-V is not installed, not available (you need Windows edition > Home) or just misconfigured.

Also, I never got any of those "advanced", supposedly better emulators (Microsoft, Xamarin, Genymotion) to work inside a VM. (Either the android screen stays black or they take a long long time to start.) Perhaps your issue is related to that?

The stock Android emulators (by Google) don't have those nifty tricks and they work just fine also within a VM. Also, if you enable the hardware acceleration there (only for Intel, I think? you need to install a [HAXM driver](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)) they also become quite a bit faster. Worst restriction there is that you cannot combine snapshots and GPU acceleration.